# Need guidance for creating a web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-studio

I wanted to create a SharePoint Visual Web Part using VS2013.

Web Part will show some Google Charts.
Data is fetched from a SharePoint List and manipulated using DataTable and Data will then bind to a GridView and this GridView will act as actual source for Google Charts.

When I tried to add a Visual Web Part it didn't let me create a project since I am working on a remote SharePoint(on-premise) site. I don't have access to same server.

Kindly suggest me which option should be most suitable for this type of situation. Also, we'll be moving the web part from site to site or server to server. So it should be easily do able.

Comment: You can install sharepoint foundation server 2013 on your machine which is free of cost. And create your solution there and then take the wsp of your solution and just deploy on your production server.

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Whats is wsp? and how I can deploy it on production server?

Comment: WSP is a file extension for a solution file used by windows. WSP stands for Windows Sharepoint. WSP files are CAB files containing a set of features, site definitions, and assemblies that can be applied to a group of computers. WSP files are reusable and easily distributable; different features of the “Solution” can be enabled or disabled selectively.

Comment: Refer this link regarding how to deploy wsp, http://www.concurrency.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp/

Comment: Does the above link applies to SharePoint 2013 also?

Comment: Yes there is no change in deployment of wsp in 2010 or 2013